# Why grand total not not working in php code?

Tags: php, html, html-table

When I am generating the total amount then it is showing just the last line sub total. I There is some mistake in that code. Total sum not showing.
Grand total showing always error.
Total sum not showing there.
Please help me out.
When adding so many services and it has different different price. In that case total amount not showing there. Only showing the last service cost. I have also added screen short below. Check it to know the more details.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" border="1"> 
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Services Details</th>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>  
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $ret = "select tblservices.ServiceName, tblservices.ServicePrice  
        from  tblinvoice 
        join tblservices on tblservices.ID=tblinvoice.ServiceId 
        where tblinvoice.BillingId=:invid";
    $query1 = $dbh -> prepare($ret);
    $query1->bindParam(':invid',$invid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query1->execute();

    $results = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $cnt = 1;
    if($query1->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        foreach($results as $row1)
        {               ?>

            <tr>
            <th><?php echo $cnt;?></th>
            <td><?php echo $row1->ServiceName?></td>    
            <td><?php echo "₹".$subtotal=$row1->ServicePrice?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php $cnt = $cnt+1;
        }
        $gtotal += $subtotal;
    } ?>

    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Grand Total</th>
        <th><?php echo "₹".$gtotal?></th>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your $gtotal is outside of your foreach loop so it's only getting the last value. Move it one line up, inside of the brace, and it will work.

Comment: Put `$gtotal += $subtotal;` inside the foreach. If you use it after, `$gtotal` will only contain the value from the last `$subtotal`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$gtotal += $subtotal;` should be in the `foreach` loop to sum it while we iterate.

```
<?php
    $ret = "select tblservices.ServiceName, tblservices.ServicePrice  
        from  tblinvoice 
        join tblservices on tblservices.ID=tblinvoice.ServiceId 
        where tblinvoice.BillingId=:invid";
    $query1 = $dbh -> prepare($ret);
    $query1->bindParam(':invid',$invid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query1->execute();

    $results = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $cnt = 1;
    if($query1->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        foreach($results as $row1)
        {               ?>

            <tr>
            <th><?php echo $cnt;?></th>
            <td><?php echo $row1->ServiceName?></td>    
            <td><?php echo "₹".$subtotal=$row1->ServicePrice?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php $cnt = $cnt+1;
              $gtotal += $subtotal;
        }
       
    } ?>
```

Comment: Client details and invoice id showing two times....why?

Comment: AsiI can see you don't have `client details` and `invoice id` in the provided img and in the code too.